# How to query One-to-Squillions

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I have 2 classes.

**User class**

```
@Entity("user")
public class User {

    @Id
    ObjectId id;

    String companyName;
    String email;

    private byte[] image;
}
```

**Ticket class:** ownerId reference to 'user' table

```
@Entity("ticket")
public class Ticket {

    @Id
    private ObjectId id;

    private ObjectId ownerId;
}
```

I want to fetch users that is ticket's owner. What is the best way to do that with Morphia?

Answer (score 1):

```
@Entity("ticket")
public class Ticket {

    @Id
    private ObjectId id;

    @Reference
    private User user;
}
```

So whenever you fetch a ticket, you can directly access the user.